# getting error on running selenium script self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using selenium with python and i try to click but every time shows the error (in starting was working)
only getting error on this line and have tried CSS selector id and all.

```
    <span class="avatar" ng-click="showBlock($event);">
                        <img src="assets/images/user.png" alt="user image">
                    </span> 

selenium code ::
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//img[@alt="user image"]'))).click()

ERROR::
 self._execute(Command.CLICK_ELEMENT)
 return self._parent.execute(command, params)
 self.error_handler.check_response(response)

raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Element <img src="assets/images/user.png" alt="user image"> is not clickable at point (1333, 34). Other element would receive the click: <div id="page_preloader" style="display: block;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.122)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.43.600210 (68dcf5eebde37173d4027fa8635e332711d2874a),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18363 x86_64)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to click the parent `span`

```
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,'//img[@alt="user image"]/parent::span'))).click()
```

if this does not work, try JS click:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//img[@alt="user image"]")
driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", el);
```